# how to add more items to column in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

i'm not english so sorry for typing problems

i'm writing a little version of instagram,and in my main page in start, i have 10 post(text for test) and in the end of that a button . when user clicks on the button i want to add 10 more post(text) to the end of the previous posts and before the button. so now i should have 20 posts(text) and button.(the size of width is fixed but height will grow)
i'm doing this with columns.

can you guys help me with this? a code that show the way in enough

and addition if you can answer:
is there any way to make a scrollable column without scrollbar showing?(like table i guess)because its make the app a little ill-sorted.

Any explanation and help is appreciated.
and i'm new to PySimpleGUI
thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkGreen')
layout = [
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(80, 15), autoscroll=True, no_scrollbar=True, key='ML')],
    [sg.Button("User 1"), sg.Push(), sg.Button("User 2")],
]
window = sg.Window('Chat', layout, finalize=True)
ml = window['ML']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ("User 1", "User 2"):
        ml.update(event+": Hello !\n", append=True)

window.close()
```

You can use method `window.extend_layout` to add new layout inside a `Column` element, remember to call `column.contents_changed()` to update the scroll region.

Here `column.contents_changed()` replaced by tkinter code `canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def repack(widget, option):
    pack_info = widget.pack_info()
    pack_info.update(option)
    widget.pack(**pack_info)

def configure_canvas(event, canvas, frame_id):
    canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())

def configure_frame(event, canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def cell(i):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Hello World', expand_x=True, key=f'TA{i}'),
         sg.Text('Hello World', expand_x=True, justification='center', key=f'TB{i}')]
    ]
    return [[sg.Frame(f'Frame {i}', layout, background_color='blue', expand_x=True, key=f'FRAME{i}')]]


layout = [
    [sg.Button('New Frame')],
    [sg.Column(cell(0), scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='COLUMN')],
]
location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, margins=(0, 0), location=location)

repack(window[f'TA{0}'].widget, {'fill':'none', 'expand':0, 'before':window[f'TB{0}'].widget})

column = window['COLUMN'].widget
frame_id, frame, canvas = column.frame_id, column.TKFrame, column.canvas

canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas, frame_id=frame_id:configure_canvas(event, canvas, frame_id))
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:configure_frame(event, canvas))

window.set_size((320, 240))
window.refresh()
window.move_to_center()

count = 1

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'New Frame':
        window.extend_layout(window['COLUMN'], cell(count))
        repack(window[f'TA{count}'].widget, {'fill':'none', 'expand':0, 'before':window[f'TB{count}'].widget})
        count += 1

window.close()
```

Note: Lot of tkinter code here, so no more information about how they work.

Comment: tnx for code but this code is a good demo for a chat-like program, but i have something entirely different. i said text for test, but in actual its a frame with texts, pictures and even a input element(for every post)

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: thank you!, this is exactly what i wanted. i'm not familiar with ktinker but it will be a good practice for me.(btw, the  `window.set_size((320, 240))` is wrong, `window.set_min_size(size=(320, 240))` is correct).

Comment: IMO, nothing wrong for `window.set_size((320, 240))`.

Comment: but i get a error for `window.set_size((320, 240))`, "Window object has no attribute set_size"

Comment: Added method @ version 4.61.0.49, you can update PySimpleGUI from Github.